# Responsive Winforms - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Actualmente estoy utilizando winforms para varias apps en la empresa donde trabajo pero ultimamente me solicitan que sea responsive la visualizacion de los textbox,datagridview, y webbrowser pero no logro hacerlo puedo con la propiedad anchor decir que no se expanda o si lo haga pero requiero es que cuando se ajuste la ventana form, todo lo de adentro se acomode no se corte

En este caso como se fijan se cortan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el excel es responsive internamente pero si sigo corriendo la ventana se va a esconder porque el datagridview no se minimiza y el de la mitad peor se borra no se acomoda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible ?

Comment: estan mal las propiedades entonces.. con anchor deberias poder ir cerrando todo.. tal vez deberias meter todo en frames....

Comment: como asi en frames, he jugado ya un buen rato con el anchor para ver si logro pero no es posible al final se cortan todos y no mantienen su aspecto

Comment: Habria que ver tu form (lo cual entiendo es muy dificil de pasar por aca)... pero hay un componente llamado panel (me confundi de nombre, perdon) que autoajusta su contenido con las propiedades dock y anchor.. tambien tenes flowlayoutpanel y algun otro con los cuales jugar....

Comment: lo voy a probar y te cuento muchas Gracias porque me dijeron que me fuera a WPF pero se complica porque no lo manejo

Comment: lo estoy probando y funciona pero se vuelve una sopa de letras con los botones pero si es lo que necesitaba gracias

Comment: WPF es una solucion muchisimo mejor, ademas de mas moderna, que permite mas manejo de todas estas cosas... y sobre todo, te va a permitir ir a MAUI que es la proxima evolucion en UI... winforms ya quedo viejo hace tiempo....

Comment: Listo hare los dos para aprender muchas Gracias!